# Use custom paths to store config files in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, embedded-tomcat-8

In embedded-tomcat can we use our custom `web.xml, server.xml`and`context.xml` files? If it is possible, can we use a custom location to store them and point that location?
It would be great if someone can point an example

I'm using Tomcat version 8.0.20.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that these configuration files are not directly supported for an embedded Tomcat implementation. The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958412/passing-a-custom-server-xml-file-to-standalone-tomcat-embedded-tomcat has more detail.